# How to make a closure as function parameter optional

Tags: ios, swift

I have a helper to display an AlertView:

```
func showAlertBoxOK(headline:String, message:String, OkButtonText:String, viewController:UIViewController, completionOK:() -> Void){

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: headline, message: message, preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: OkButtonText, style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default)
        { action -> Void in
            if completionOK() != nil {
                completionOK()
            }
        })
    viewController.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Now I would like to make the parameter `completionOK`optional. I´ve tried
completionOK:() -> Void? = nil` but his gives me a compiler error. My calls should be like this without parameter:

```
showAlertBoxOK("Could not retrieve position", "Edit iOS Settings - GeoLocation denied. Sorry. Please fix that und restart App.", "OK", self)
```

and with parameter as this:

```
showAlertBoxOK("Could not retrieve position", "Edit iOS Settings - GeoLocation denied. Sorry. Please fix that und restart App.", "OK", self, { println("hello world") })
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a different approach and define the parameter with a default value, like this:

```
func showAlertBoxOK(headline:String, message:String, OkButtonText:String, viewController:UIViewController, completionOK:() -> Void = {}){

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: headline, message: message, preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: OkButtonText, style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default)
        { action -> Void in
            completionOK()
        })
    viewController.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

In this way you can call the function in the two different ways, and also you simplify the definition of the function.

Comment: You are missing a parentheses: `completionOK:() -> Void = {})` must be `completionOK:(() -> Void)? = {}`. But you are right. Thanks

Comment: It is more simple to *not* define as optional the closure, since one is always provided, and also remove the '!' form the call. I edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this;

```
func showAlertBoxOK(headline:String, message:String, OkButtonText:String, viewController:UIViewController, completionOK:(() -> Void)? = nil){

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: headline, message: message, preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: OkButtonText, style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default)
        { action -> Void in
            if completionOK != nil {
                completionOK!()
            }
        })
    viewController.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: this gives me a compiler error for the line `if completionOK != nil {`

Comment: It is working fine on swift 1.2. ?? did you make changes on function's parameter ..., completionOK:(() -> Void)? = nil

Answer (score 0):

To mark a closure parameter as optional you have to wrap the closure type in parentheses:

```
(() -> Void)?
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create optional block this way `completionOK:(() -> ()?)?`

and your function will be:

```
func showAlertBoxOK(headline:String, message:String, OkButtonText:String, viewController:UIViewController, completionOK:(() -> ()?)?){

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: headline, message: message, preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: OkButtonText, style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default)
        { action -> Void in
            if let block = completionOK{  //unwrap your block this way.
                println("Block is not empty")
                block()
            } else {
                println("Block is empty")
            }
        })
    viewController.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

And now you can use it this way without parameter:

```
showAlertBoxOK("Could not retrieve position", message: "Edit iOS Settings - GeoLocation denied. Sorry. Please fix that und restart App.", OkButtonText: "OK", viewController: self, completionOK: nil)
```

And with parameter:

```
showAlertBoxOK("Could not retrieve position", message: "Edit iOS Settings - GeoLocation denied. Sorry. Please fix that und restart App.", OkButtonText: "OK", viewController: self, completionOK: { println("hello world") })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func showAlertBoxOK(headline:String, message:String, OkButtonText:String, viewController:UIViewController, completion: (() -> Void)?){

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: headline, message: message, preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: OkButtonText, style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default)
        { action -> Void in
            if ((completion) != nil) {
                completion!()
            }
        })
    viewController.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```